# Java - How to Give method an array

Tags: java, methods, processbuilder

I have a method like the following:

```
public void launch(String cmd, String [] args, String workingDir)
```

Inside this method I call [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

How can I call ProcessBuilder including an arbitrary number of args included in my args parameter?

E.g., something like this:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd, args);
```

I notice ProcessBuilder does have this contructor:

```
ProcessBuilder(List<String> command)
```

Maybe I could use that somehow.

Comment: Yes, you can use that constructor as demonstrated in the answers below. You can set the passed working directory with ProcessBuilder.directory(). Also, one gotcha that hits many first-time users of ProcessBuilder is the need to consume the output and error streams of the process. See Process.getInputStream() and Process.getErrorStream().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ProcessBuilder has a [varargs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) Constructor - `ProcessBuilder(String... command)` - so you can use that, but you'll need to make your command and arguments into a single array.

Otherwise you can use the other Constructor as follows:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(args.length + 1);
list.add(cmd)
list.addAll(Arrays.asList(args));
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(list);
```

Answer (score 7):

How about:

```
public static void launch(String cmd, String[] args, String workingDir) {
    List<String> strArgs = new ArrayList<String>();
    strArgs.add(cmd);
    strArgs.addAll(Arrays.asList(args));
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(strArgs);
}
```